# Find folder with approximate name

Tags: vb.net

I currently have a routine that searches up through the directory where a file is saved and finds a folder called "$Fabrication Data".
I am working on a new addition that will be subbed into my existing code to allow for some human error, aka slight misspelling/misformating if that folder name.
I would like to examine each folder in the 'Path' directory (but not its sub folders). Currently it returns a match:
Path\SubFolder$Fabrication Data$
instead if the path I want:
Path$ Fabrication Data

Bonus question... I am currently returning any folder that is above a .8 match, how can I return the closest match if there are multiple folders above .8 match?

````
Dim Path As String = "N:\Stuff\More Stuff\More More Stuff\Project Folder"

For Each d In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(Path)
    For Each sDir In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(d)
        Dim sdirInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(sDir)
        Dim similarity As Single = GetSimilarity(sdirInfo.Name, "$Fabrication Data")
        If similarity > .8 Then
            sFDPath = Path & "\" & sdirInfo.Name
            
            MsgBox(sFDPath)
            Else
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub

Public Function GetSimilarity(string1 As String, string2 As String) As Single
    Dim dis As Single = ComputeDistance(string1, string2)
    Dim maxLen As Single = string1.Length
    If maxLen < string2.Length Then
        maxLen = string2.Length
    End If
    If maxLen = 0.0F Then
        Return 1.0F
    Else
        Return 1.0F - dis / maxLen
    End If
End Function

Private Function ComputeDistance(s As String, t As String) As Integer
    Dim n As Integer = s.Length
    Dim m As Integer = t.Length
    Dim distance As Integer(,) = New Integer(n, m) {}
    ' matrix
    Dim cost As Integer = 0
    If n = 0 Then
        Return m
    End If
    If m = 0 Then
        Return n
    End If
    'init1

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While i <= n
            distance(i, 0) = System.Math.Min(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(i), i - 1)
        End While
        Dim j As Integer = 0
        While j <= m
            distance(0, j) = System.Math.Min(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(j), j - 1)
        End While
    'find min distance

    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To m
            cost = (If(t.Substring(j - 1, 1) = s.Substring(i - 1, 1), 0, 1))
            distance(i, j) = Math.Min(distance(i - 1, j) + 1, Math.Min(distance(i, j - 1) + 1, distance(i - 1, j - 1) + cost))
        Next
    Next
    Return distance(n, m)
End Function ```
````

Comment: You can create a List of similarity ratings. You can then sort this list and take the last item once the list is sorted, it should be the folder with the highest rating.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the ratings for each folder using a simple class like this:

```
Public Class FolderRating

    Public Rating As Single
    Public Folder As String

    Public Sub New(folder As String, rating As Single)
        Me.Folder = folder
        Me.Rating = rating
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then, create a List:

```
Dim ratings As New List(Of FolderRating)
```

In your loop, when you find a rating that is above 0.8, add it to the list:

```
If similarity > 0.8 Then
    Dim sFDPath As String = Path & "\" & sdirInfo.Name
    ratings.Add(New FolderRating(sFDPath, similarity))
End If
```

Finally, sort the list:

```
ratings.Sort(Function(x, y) x.Rating.CompareTo(y.Rating))
```

You can then take the last value in the list and it will be your most similar folder, if any:

```
Dim bestMatch As FolderRating = ratings.LastOrDefault
```